# function that can manipulate a column

Tags: r

```
id <- (3,3,6,4)
seq <- (4,7,9,10)
code <- ("009","008","7994","5715","9008","73638967","780092","7994906","0068923") 




providedstring <- c('009','006,'8967','7994')
```

I have tried using str_detect and filter.

```
filter(str_detect(code,providedstring))
```

and this gives me an error:

```
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Desired output:

```
id <- (3,6)
seq <- (4,9)
code <- (009,7994906,0068923)
```

Comment: The sample code is not valid R code. Please fix your post (you're missing the `c(...)`s). Also your column vectors have different numbers of entries. Please use `dput` to show your `data.frame`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

```
id <- c(3,3,6,4)
seq <- c(4,7,9,10)
code <- c('009','008','7994','5715') 
providedstring <- c('009','006','8967','7994')
# add ^ in front of providedstring to specify we want match only for start
providedstring <- paste0("^",providedstring)
# create dataframe with 3 columns
df <-  data.frame(id=id,seq=seq,code=code)
# filter rows that contain one of the codes in provided string
df %>% 
   filter(str_detect(code,paste(providedstring,collapse="|")))
```

Comment: thank you! could you reread the question, I edited it so it makes a bit more sense to what I am asking exactly

Comment: you just need to add this line `providedstring <- paste0("^",providedstring)`, I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Now try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame( 
  id = c(1:9),
  seq = c(9:1),
  code = c("009","008","7994","5715","9008","73638967","780092","7994906","0068923") 
)
providedstring <- c("009","006","8967","7994")
a <- sapply(providedstring, function(x) as.numeric(str_starts(df$code, x))) 
df$yes <- apply(a, 1, max)
df %>% filter(yes ==1)
```

It will produce:

```
  id seq    code yes
1  1   9     009   1
2  3   7    7994   1
3  8   2 7994906   1
4  9   1 0068923   1
```

Comment: I also want that the output would be that its only starting with those "providedstring" , so for example code = c("009","008876","787009","7842834008") I want it to only return, code = ("009",008876") because it only started with that specific pattern, Hopefully that makes sense! and thank you

Comment: Not sure if I understand. Could you please revise your question and desired output to reflect that?

Comment: I edited my question, I hope that makes sense

Comment: I have revised my answer, and let me know if it is not what you are looking for.